# Convert between 2 module by interface

Tags: java

Suppose I have 2 general type of Module Earth/Mars. So there will be EarthPerson,EarthDog and MarsPerson, MarsDog etc. They can convert to each other by implements an interface to make sure they can convert to each other but still remain the same type.Ex: person can only be person not dog.

```
public interface Mars<T extends Earth> {
    T toEarth();
    interface Earth<T extends Mars<V>,V extends Earth>{
        T toMars();
    }
}
```

Somehow I think those wildcards seems to much complex. But it keeps the TypeSafety for me. 
So my question is how can I restructure this?

Comment: This is really weird. Why would a `MarsPerson` become an `EarthPerson`? If it's a person from Mars, then it is *not* a person from Earth. My point is that this might indicate some error in your design

Comment: Sounds like you rather need an abstract(?) class called Person and then extend with MarsPerson/EarthPerson?

Comment: @ViktorMellgren If it was only about Persons and Dogs, then maybe yes. But what if you also want to handle Cats, Horses and Birds on Jupiter, Pluto and Venus? Think about all the combinations you have to create!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example's semantic is a little awkward, but you could tackle the problem by applying a [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Java). The resulting client code could look like this:

```
@Test
public void testPerson() {
    InterplanetaryTravelling<Person> traveller = new Person();
    assertEquals("", traveller.whereWasI());

    traveller = new ToEarth<>(traveller);
    assertEquals("Earth", traveller.getCurrentPlanet());
    assertEquals("Earth", traveller.whereWasI());

    traveller = new ToMars<>(traveller);
    assertEquals("Mars", traveller.getCurrentPlanet());
    assertEquals("Earth, Mars", traveller.whereWasI());
}

@Test
public void testDog() {
    InterplanetaryTravelling<Dog> traveller = new Shepherd();
    assertEquals("", traveller.whereWasI());
    // ... same as for the person
}

@Test
public void testTypeSafety() {
    InterplanetaryTravelling<Person> traveller = new Shepherd(); // Compiler Error
}
```

It's an effective solution, as you implement type-dependent code only once. It's also scalable, as for each new type, you'll create just one new class instead of having to create classes for each possible combination of types.

My decorator has the following implementation:

```
interface InterplanetaryTravelling<T> {
    String getCurrentPlanet();

    String whereWasI();
}

abstract class InterplanetaryTravellingDecorator<S> implements InterplanetaryTravelling<S> {

    private final InterplanetaryTravelling<? extends S> decoratedTraveller;

    InterplanetaryTravellingDecorator(InterplanetaryTravelling<? extends S> traveller) {
        this.decoratedTraveller = traveller;
    }

    @Override
    public String whereWasI() {
        String previousTravels = decoratedTraveller.whereWasI();

        return previousTravels.isEmpty() ? this.getCurrentPlanet()
                : previousTravels + ", " + this.getCurrentPlanet();
    }
}

class ToEarth<S> extends InterplanetaryTravellingDecorator<S> {

    ToEarth(InterplanetaryTravelling<? extends S> person) {
        super(person);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentPlanet() {
        return "Earth";
    }

}

class ToMars<S> extends InterplanetaryTravellingDecorator<S> {

    ToMars(InterplanetaryTravelling<? extends S> person) {
        super(person);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentPlanet() {
        return "Mars";
    }

}

class Person implements InterplanetaryTravelling<Person> {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentPlanet() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String whereWasI() {
        return "";
    }

}

abstract class Dog implements InterplanetaryTravelling<Dog> {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentPlanet() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String whereWasI() {
        return "";
    }

}

class Shepherd extends Dog { }
```

Still, it looks complicated with these generic boundaries, but I wanted to prevent the declaration of an `InterplanetaryTravelling traveller`, that could reference both a person and/or a dog.

Comment: Not exactly what I want before but it really open my mind. Thx for this answer.